# Function to check dimension value and what it is

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I am trying to write a program that checks to see if a dimension of a rectangle is greater than zero. In the void function Check i tried using an array to check the value and used a string to display what dimension was wrong to the user. I am getting an error that it "cannot convert argument 1 from 'double[6]' to 'double'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Check(double, string);

int main()
{
    const int size = 3;
    double DimArray[size];
    string MyArray[size] = { "Height", "Length", "Width"};

    cout << "Enter the height, length and width of rectangle: ";
    cin >> DimArray[0] >> DimArray[1] >> DimArray[2];

    Check(DimArray, MyArray);

    return 0;
}

void Check(double arr1[], string arr2[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (arr1[i] <= 0)
          cout << "Your entered " << arr2[i] << "is less than zero!";
        cout << "Please enter a valid number --> ";
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing arrays that contain 3 elements but the `Check` function is iterating over 4 elements. Accessing an element outside the bounds of an array results in [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). I suggest either using `std::array` or `std::vector` **or** pass the size of the arrays to `Check`.

Answer (score 4):

You should declare the function correctly. Instead of

```
void Check(double, string);
```

there should be

```
void Check( double[], const std::string[], size_t );
```

Also instead of the loop in the function body

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

there must be

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

And the function could be defined as

```
void Check( double arr1[], const std::string arr2[], size_t n )
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
   {
       while ( arr1[i] <= 0 )
       {
            std::cout << "Your entered " << arr2[i] << "is not positive!\n";
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid number --> ";
            std::cin >> arr1[i];
       }
   }
}
```

Or if you will define file-wide constant

```
const size_t SIZE = 3;
```

then the function definition (and correspondingly its declaration) could be simplified

```
void Check( double arr1[], const std::string arr2[] )
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ )
   {
       while ( arr1[i] <= 0 )
       {
            std::cout << "Your entered " << arr2[i] << "is not positive!\n";
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid number --> ";
            std::cin >> arr1[i];
       }
   }
}
```

Also instead of the array of std::string(s) it would be better to define an array of `const char *`

```
const char * MyArray[size] = { "Height", "Length", "Width"};
```

because as I have understood you are not going to change it.

Comment: +1 for using `size_t` and a `while` loop to prevent entering another 0 as the replacement value

Answer (score 2):

Since your prototype expects a type `double` and you are passing a `double arr1[]`..

Change the prototype:

```
void Check(double, string);
```

to:

```
void Check(double arr1[], string arr2[])
```